# Biblatex: wrap postnote to \cite command in parentheses

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

I'm using biblatex with the authoryear-comp style.  By default, the `\cite` command prints citations with no parentheses.  I would like to keep this behavior while putting any *postnote* in parenthes following the citation, like this: See Author 2020 (postnote).  For other citation commands I still want the regular punctuation (a comma, by default), e.g. `\textcite` should produce Author (2020, postnote) and `\parencite` should produce (Author 2020, postnote).

I have tried to achieve this by redefining `\cite` with `\DeclareCiteCommand` so that it doesn't call the `postnote` bibmacro (which inserts `postnotedelim`) but instead calls a new macro that wraps the argument in parenthese.  But when I do this I get an undesired semicolon in front of my postnote.  I can make this go away with `\nopunct` but I still get an undesired space, which does not go away even if I add `\unspace`.  I don't understand where all this punctuation is coming from since I am not calling `postnotedelim`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{myarticle,
        author = {Doe, John},
        year = {2020},
        title = {The Title}}    
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{plainpostnote}{#1}

\newbibmacro{parenpostnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\addspace\mkbibparens{%\nopunct\unspace
     \printfield[plainpostnote]{postnote}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite} %
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{parenpostnote}}

\begin{document}
    This is plain \cite[note]{myarticle} and this is text: \textcite[note]{myarticle} and this is parenthetical \parencite[note]{myarticle}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Desired output: This is plain Doe 2020 (note) and this is text: Doe (2020, note) and this is parenthetical (Doe 2020, note).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick way to do that that uses that `postnotedelim` is context sensitive in new `biblatex` versions and introduces a context sensitive wrapper for the postnote field format as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[cite]{postnotedelim}{\addspace}

% default postnote wrapper does nothing
\newcommand*{\postnotewrapper}[1]{#1}
% \cite postnote wrapper wraps argument in round brackets
\newcommand*{\postnotewrappercite}{\mkbibparens}

\makeatletter
% apply context-sensitive wrapper
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{%
  \ifcsundef{postnotewrapper\blx@delimcontext}
    {\postnotewrapper}
    {\csuse{postnotewrapper\blx@delimcontext}}%
  {\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  This is plain \cite[note]{sigfridsson}
  and this is text \textcite[note]{sigfridsson}
  and this is parenthetical \parencite[note]{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

[image: This is plain Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998 (note) and this is text Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, note) and this is parenthetical (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, note).]

---

The undesirable punctuation in the code from the question is caused by not using the `biblatex` punctuation tracker and by applying a formatting macro like `\mkbibparens` directly in a bibmacro. If you just write `\addspace\mkbibparens{...}` in a bibmacro, then the punctuation will not go via the punctuation tracker, it is printed directly. Since `authoryear-comp` heavily relies on the punctuation tracker you get weird results like this, because the punctuation tracker is not cleared and its contents are then printed inside the parentheses when you call `\printfield`.

Comment: Thank you - excellent solution and informative answer.